# Grails config of Spring beans in different files

Tags: java, grails, groovy, maven, config

Grails have cofig for spring bean called `resources.groovy`. And as i understand from docs it allows you to include another file, using loadBeans(%path%)

I'm tried with this:

```
println 'loading application config ...'


// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    loadBeans("classpath:security") //i'm tried with "spring/security" and "spring/security.groovy" also

}
```

but when grails is running it log following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Error evaluating bean definition script: class path resource [security] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Offending resource: class path resource [security]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [security] cannot be opened because it does not exist
 at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.loadBeans(BeanBuilder.java:470)
 at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.loadBeans(BeanBuilder.java:424)
 at resources$_run_closure1.doCall(resources.groovy:13)
 at resources$_run_closure1.doCall(resources.groovy)
 ... 45 more
```

Script `security.groovy` is exists at `grails-app/conf/spring` and compiled by *grails maven plugin* into `target/classes/security.class`.
Directory `target/resources/spring` is empty at this time

How i can configure Grails or grails-maven-plugin to copy this config files, not compile it into classes?

p.s. this problem also presents when i try to include config scripts using `grails.config.locations = [ %path% ]` inside `conf/Config.groovy`, my groovy scripts compiles into classes and because of it, grails config builder can't find them :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Did you try:</strike>

```
println 'loading application config ...'


// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    loadBeans("classpath:*security.groovy") 

}
```

(this should load all Groovy files on the classpath ending with `security.groovy` and parse them into bean definitions).

**Update:** Found an [interesting thread](http://www.pubbs.net/grails/200912/7717/) with [this message](http://old.nabble.com/classpath-issue-td25989289.html) as reference and my understanding is that one trick is to use ant in `scripts/_Events.groovy` to copy the `.groovy` file to the `classesDirPath` dir and then simply use:

```
beans = {
    // load spring-beans for db-access via spring-jdbc-template
    loadBeans('security.groovy')

    // load some other spring-beans
        ...
}
```

This looks like a hack to get things working in both the war and when running run-app though. Not sure how things "should" be done (if this even makes sense).

Comment: tried, but with no success :( And also there aro no any security.groovy anywhere in classpath, grails compiled it into security.class I thins that it the root of problem, but don't know how to fix this

Comment: @Pascal Thivent Can you re-post / update the links to Nabble?  They appear to be missing...

Comment: I tried the following in _Event and it worked.       eventCompileEnd = {
    ant.copy(file: "${basedir}/grails-app/conf/spring/security.groovy", todir: classesDirPath)
}