# Spring DSL in Grails - resources.groovy - bean configuration in a different file?

Tags: spring, grails, dependency-injection, spring-dsl

This question [already exists in a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276823/grails-config-of-spring-beans-in-different-files), but the existing question is missing some important links.

I'm trying to move the configuration of beans for my tests into separate files that end in `*TestsSpringBeans.groovy`

I've attempted to do this after reading ["Loading Bean Definitions from the File System"](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html) (search for it) in the Groovy documentation.

Here are the relevant code segments:

```
import grails.util.*

beans = {
...
  switch(Environment.current) {
    case Environment.TEST:
      loadBeans("classpath:*TestsSpringBeans.groovy")
      break
    }
}
```

**resources.groovy** - Loading the *TestSpringBeans files from the File System.

---

```
somePlace(jobdb.Company) {
    name = "SomeCompany"
    addr1 = "addr1"
    addr2 = "addr2"
    city = "city"
    email = "somedude@h0tmail.com"
    fax = "555-555-5555"
    phone = "444-444-4444"
    state = "PA"
    zip = "19608"
    version: 0
    created = new Date()
    updated = new Date()
    website = "http://www.yahoo.com"
    deleted = false
  }
```

### **CompanyServiceTestsSpringBeans.groovy** - Defining a bean for the Integration Test

```
// Retrieve configured bean from 
Company someplace = ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getMainContext().getBean('somePlace')
```

**CompanyServiceTests.groovy** - Obtain the bean `somePlace` within the Integration Test...

Upon calling `getBean('somePlace')` within the test an error is displayed which reads that  `No bean named 'somePlace' is defined`

The `CompanyServiceTests.groovy` file is stored with my integration tests, should I be storing this file somewhere else in the project directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

Since your tests run in a way that using the classpath as a reference point is less important, you might try to load the beans { ... } file by referencing via project directory specific path. (e.g. $baseDir/test/resources/MyCustomBeans.groovy) or load the beans explicitly in your tests via @BeforeClass if you are using JUnit4 annotations:

```
def bb = new BeanBuilder()
def resource = new FileSystemResource('src/test/resources/testContext.groovy')
bb.loadBeans(resource)
appCtx = bb.createApplicationContext()
...
```